# ConTeXt: difference between text and label in referenceformat

Tags: context

When we read [the documentation page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setupreferenceformat) of `\setupreferenceformat` we can find those two lines:

> **label** Label inserted before the `left`. Mutually exclusive with `text`.

> **text** Text inserted before the `left`. Mutually exclusive with `label`.

1. So, what is the difference between those two?
2. Subsidiary question: if I understand correctly since those two are always inserted before `left`, there is no option, let's say, for a reference with `left=(` and `right=)` to get `({label|text} counter)`. It will always be `{label|text} (counter)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `text=Text`, you get exactly `Text`.

If you use `label=figure` (for example), you get the labeltext for the `figure` label in the language used. So, you can get different outputs, depending on what language is set. See also `\setuplabeltext`.